# Pandas: Efficient way to extract a string into individual columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a following string in a pandas dataframe column named "Fields". The column "Fields" is a single column extracted from a csv file.
Given 1170 rows in the entire dataframe, if I were to parse these values into individual column, it takes 6 minutes and 30 seconds using pandas str split or a regex. Is there any efficient way to perform this task in faster manner?

Example using Pandas split:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df['uuid'][i] = row['Arguments'].split("uuid=")[1].split(',')[0]
```

Example using regex:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    arg = row['Fields']
    
    uuid = re.search('driveUuid=(.+?),', arg).group(1)
    line = re.search('line=(.+?),', arg).group(1)
```

I have a way around it, but doesn't seem efficient.

One entry of the column "Fields"

> uuid=88c65b1d,line=main,serial=ABC12312,location=top:6,slot=6,floor=top,version=E004

Comment: Try [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

Comment: @HenryYik, extract was much faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
d['uuid'] = d['Fields'].str.extract('uuid=(.+?),')
```

As noted by [Henry Yik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9284423/henry-yik) in a comment

```
d["Fields"].str.extract('(?:drive)?Uuid=(.+?),line=(.+?),', flags=re.I)
```

Comment: Looking at your sample you can actually do `d["Fields"].str.extract('(?:drive)?Uuid=(.+?),line=(.+?),', flags=re.I)`.